# How can I switch scenes using a controller class, with ActionEvent as parameter?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to make a basic GUI that can switch between scenes. I know this question has been asked before and believe me, I've tried to look for the solution for several hours already to no avail, so I resort to this.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class MainMenuController implements Initializable {

public void startNewGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent tableViewParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Game.fxml"));
    Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(tableViewParent);

    Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    window.setScene(tableViewScene);
    window.show();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}
```

And here is the main app:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Main Menu");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

When I run this it gives this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#startNewGame', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
...

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:618)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:778)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at GUI.MainApplication.start(MainApplication.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application GUI.MainApplication
```

So I know it is caused by the method to handle the button action. I can successfully make other buttons with actions as long as they do not have parameter `ActionEvent`.

It seems whenever I add this parameter to access the action event this method is not recognized. I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong in setting up the main app or controller or maybe even the fxml. I have looked through so many tutorials and don't really understand it because I have something similar.

here are the fxml files. Starting scene (`MainMenu.fxml`):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

    <AnchorPane fx:id="ap" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="658.0" prefWidth="885.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="GUI.MainMenuController">
       <children>
          <Label fx:id="title" layoutX="322.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="Text Adventure">
             <font>
                <Font size="35.0" />
             </font>
          </Label>
          <Button layoutX="384.0" layoutY="204.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#startNewGame" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="Start New Game" />
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Scene that will be switched to (`Game.fxml`):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="658.0" prefWidth="885.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="GUI.GameController">
   <children>
      <RadioButton fx:id="radio1" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="337.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radio1Click" text="RadioButton">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="group" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton fx:id="radio2" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="402.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radio2Click" text="RadioButton" toggleGroup="$group" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="radio3" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="469.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radio3Click" text="RadioButton" toggleGroup="$group" />
      <Label fx:id="output" layoutX="169.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="231.0" prefWidth="462.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post your FXML files as well?

Comment: Do you need to do `@FXML public void startNewGame(ActionEvent event)`?

Comment: @Sedrick tried that, no luck

Comment: @Abra I just edited my post with the fxml files

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting this same error "Error resolving onAction='#startNewGame', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script." after following what Sedrick wrote?

Comment: @Robert yes, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of headaches and wasted time the answer for was that Netbeans imported the wrong version of ActionEvent (the java.awt version rather than javafx version). On the off chance someone encounters this problem in the future, make sure you are importing this way:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```